# Getting Rid of the Older Record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is a result set where all the records are unique columns like this . 
I only want to display the records with newer dates if there is another record which belongs to the same BusinessID.
My query to get this result is

```
SELECT 
  FirstName, 
  LastName,
  Department,
  StartDate,
  Title,
  PhoneNumber,
  BusinessEntityID
FROM
  (SELECT
     E.BusinessEntityID,
     H.FirstName,
     H.LastName,
     H.Title,
     H.Department,
     E.PhoneNumber,
     E.CountryRegionName,
     E.PostalCode,
     H.StartDate
   FROM 
     CS120Exam_EmployeeDepartmentHistory H
   JOIN 
     CS120Exam_Employee E
   ON 
     E.BusinessEntityID=H.BusinessEntityID ) x 
   ORDER BY BusinessEntityID
```

And the result is

```
BusinessID  FirstName LastName Department StartDate
----------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
1           aaa       mate     staff      2002-02-02 <----- DO NOT want this 
1           aaa       mate     admin      2004-03-05
2           john      mate     admin      2001-03-06
3           sun       kent     admin      2004-03-05
4           bbb       clark    staff      2006-02-02 <----- DO NOT want this 
4           bbb       clark    admin      2009-03-05
```

Comment: A question: will the `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Department` columns ever vary within one `BusinessEntityID`, or will they always be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sub-select to find the latest date for each `BusinessEntityID`. Try this (untested, of course):

```
SELECT 
  FirstName, 
  LastName,
  Department,
  StartDate,
  Title,
  PhoneNumber,
  BusinessEntityID
FROM
  (SELECT
     E.BusinessEntityID,
     H.FirstName,
     H.LastName,
     H.Title,
     H.Department,
     E.PhoneNumber,
     E.CountryRegionName,
     E.PostalCode,
     H.StartDate
   FROM 
     CS120Exam_EmployeeDepartmentHistory H
   JOIN 
     CS120Exam_Employee E
   ON 
     E.BusinessEntityID=H.BusinessEntityID ) x 
   WHERE x.StartDate = 
     (SELECT 
        Max(cs.StartDate) 
      FROM
        CS120Exam_EmployeeDepartmentHistory cs
      WHERE
        cs.BusinessEntityID = x.BusinessEntityID)
   ORDER BY BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Note: this assumes that the StartDate is unique per BusinessEntityID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY and max(startdate)

```
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  Department,
  max(StartDate),
  Title,
  PhoneNumber,
  BusinessEntityID
FROM
  (SELECT 
     E.BusinessEntityID,
     H.FirstName,
     H.LastName,
     H.Title,
     H.Department,
     E.PhoneNumber,
     E.CountryRegionName,
     E.PostalCode,
     H.StartDate
  FROM 
    CS120Exam_EmployeeDepartmentHistory H
  JOIN 
    CS120Exam_Employee E
  ON 
   E.BusinessEntityID=H.BusinessEntityID ) x 
  ORDER BY 
    BusinessEntityID
  GROUP BY 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Department,
    Title,
    PhoneNumber,
    BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your answers. You've been here long enough to know how.

Comment: that gives the same result as I receive

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of grouping by rest of columns and getting maximum of date. In this case you will get a single record with max date

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Department,max(StartDate),Title,PhoneNumber,BusinessEntityID
FROM
(SELECT E.BusinessEntityID,H.FirstName,H.LastName,H.Title,H.Department,E.PhoneNumber,
E.CountryRegionName,E.PostalCode,H.StartDate
FROM CS120Exam_EmployeeDepartmentHistory H
JOIN CS120Exam_Employee E
ON E.BusinessEntityID=H.BusinessEntityID )x 
group by  FirstName,LastName,Department,Title,PhoneNumber,BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: i see that your title differs.. that is the reason.. do u want records with different titles appear different

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  FirstName, 
  LastName,
  Department,
  StartDate,
  Title,
  PhoneNumber,
  BusinessEntityID
FROM
  (SELECT
     E.BusinessEntityID,
     H.FirstName,
     H.LastName,
     H.Title,
     H.Department,
     E.PhoneNumber,
     E.CountryRegionName,
     E.PostalCode,
     H.StartDate,
     row_number() over (partition by BusinessID order by StartDate desc) as rn
   FROM 
     CS120Exam_EmployeeDepartmentHistory H
   JOIN 
     CS120Exam_Employee E
   ON 
     E.BusinessEntityID=H.BusinessEntityID ) x 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY BusinessEntityID
```

Might be faster than using a sub-select to get the max. startdate because only a single scan over the table is required.